# How to start new intent for every whole CardView in RecycleView android?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-studio, android-intent

I've created CardView using RecycleVeiw in android now i wanna to add intent for every single each item of cardivew in recyleview kindly guide me:
screen shot of my requirement here:
[image: Like that is a cardiview and i wanna to add intent to each item]
my adapter class code is given here:

```
public class MapAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>    {

private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
private List<MapSetData> venues;
public Context context;


public MapAdapter(List<MapSetData> venues, Context context) {
    this.venues = venues;
    this.context = context;
    }

@Override
public VenuesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.map_item, viewGroup, false);
    VenuesViewHolder pvh = new VenuesViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    VenuesViewHolder holder = (VenuesViewHolder) viewHolder;                   holder.venues_picture.setImageResource(venues.get(position).venue_picture);
        holder.card_title_txt.setText(venues.get(position).card_title_txt);
        holder.location_qs.setText(venues.get(position).location_qs);
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isPositionHeader(position) == 0) {
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    } else if (isPositionHeader(position) == 1) {
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

private int isPositionHeader(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return venues.size();

}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
    }
}

public class VenuesViewHolder extends ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView venues_picture;
    TextView card_title_txt;
    TextView location_qs;
    CardView cv;
    public Context context;

    public VenuesViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        context = v.getContext();
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        venues_picture = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_picture);
        card_title_txt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_title_txt);
        location_qs = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_qs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapDetails.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: it has almost done. `setOnClickListener(this)` for each item of card view. Ex: `venues_picture.setOnClickListener(this)` and in method `onClick(View v)` check id `if(v.getId()==R.id.match_picture){//do something}`.

Comment: not every single item of cardview but every item in recycleview like whole cardview touch listener i hope to got my question

Comment: if it is the whole cardview, set  `cv.setOnClickListener(this)`. You can use getAdapterPosition() to check position for difirent cardview.

Comment: yes i want this, will you kindly give some code of piece to help me out?

Comment: It is easy. You can see some example [here](https://codentrick.com/recyclerview-example-part-3-android-recyclerview-onclicklistener/).

Comment: okay i'll check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all, i solved my problem like this,

```
public VenuesViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        context = v.getContext();
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        venues_picture = (ImageView)   itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_picture);
        card_title_txt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_title_txt);
        location_qs = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_qs);
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                if (pos == 0) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MapDetails.class));
                } else if (pos == 1) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MapDetailsTwo.class));
                } else if (pos == 2) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MapDetails.class));
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this!

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        VenuesViewHolder holder = (VenuesViewHolder) viewHolder;                            
holder.venues_picture.setImageResource(venues.get(position).venue_picture);
            holder.card_title_txt.setText(venues.get(position).card_title_txt);
            holder.location_qs.setText(venues.get(position).location_qs);

     holder.v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapDetails.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

    }
```

Comment: Yeah sure i'll try this.

Comment: would you please tell what is holder.v. i mean what is "v" here?

Comment: v is View which u passed in the constructor of ViewHolder

Comment: it's not accessed in onBindViewHolder() method,

Comment: basically cardview that showing in picture i wanna add to intent to every single item

Comment: for that You have to initialize a view in ViewHolder class that contains the picture of CardView & in onBind method You just simply set a clicklistener
on that ImageView

Comment: not every single item of cardview but every item in recycleview like whole cardview touch listener i hope to got my question

Answer (score 0):

You can set onclickListener to your cardview like this

```
public class VenuesViewHolder extends ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
ImageView venues_picture;
TextView card_title_txt;
TextView location_qs;
CardView cv;
public Context context;

public VenuesViewHolder(View v) {
    super(v);
    v.setOnClickListener(this);
    context = v.getContext();
    cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
    venues_picture = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_picture);
    card_title_txt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_title_txt);
    location_qs = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_qs);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int viewId = v.getId();
    switch(viewId){
         case R.id.cv :
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapDetails.class);
         context.startActivity(intent);
          break;
     }


}
}
```

Comment: if i add another case in switch statement then how i'll add this,because R.id.cv only one cardview is that true?

Comment: `switch(viewId){
         case R.id.cv :
             Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapDetails.class);
              context.startActivity(intent);
          break;    case R.id.match_picture:
             Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapDetails.class);
              context.startActivity(intent);
          break;
     }`

Comment: your answer is good but i need to add intent to each position in recycleview which is cardview is the single item of recycleview so i want to add intent to recyclew item not cardview

Answer (score 0):

try below code,

```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

       Intent intent;

       switch (isPositionHeader)
       {
           case 0:
            if(v.getId()==R.id.match_picture)
                        intent = new Intent(context, MapDetails.class); 

            else if(v.getId()==R.id.card_title_txt)
                        intent = new Intent(context, CardTitle.class); 
           break;



           case 1:
            if(v.getId()==R.id.match_picture)
                        intent = new Intent(context, MapDetails1.class); 

            else if(v.getId()==R.id.card_title_txt)
                        intent = new Intent(context, CardTitle1.class); 
           break;

          // And So

       }

    if(intent != null)
           startActivity(intent);
   }
```

Comment: set it as public, as currently it is private like "private int isPositionHeader()"

Comment: your answer also for each item of cardview i need whole cardview touch listener that is in recycleview

Comment: then use this line cv.setOnClickListener(this);   after initializing cv for cardview